# Does Java's implementation of a ResultSet re-execute SQL Statements to retrieve additional ResultSet data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've read on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html that MySQL's JDBC Implementation actually loads the entire result set into memory, but can also be configured to stream data row by row from the database. The process I was trying to understand is the underlying Streaming process offered by the MySQL database. When you execute a sql statement on the database, assuming that you're using MySQL's streaming feature, does the database first generate all necessary data as defined in the SQL statement and store it somewhere, then loads it row by row to an output stream which is then retrieved by MySQL connector and further loaded into a Result Set and stored in memory?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could outline this process for me.

I'm trying to understand whether it's more efficient to use SQL's `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` compared to fetching all data into a `ResultSet`.

Comment: No, the statement is executed only once. Don't manually execute several queries if one is enough. You might want to read about streams and buffering.

Comment: Also, be aware that you were looking at the documentation for the "Oracle 11g" database product while your question is tagged for MySQL. Oracle Corporation owns both the "Oracle" and "MySQL" products but they are very different creatures.

Comment: Java doesn't have an implementation of `ResultSet`. It only provides the interface `java.sql.ResultSet`. Implementation is up to individual driver implementations. You have tagged your question _mysql_, but you are quoting from Oracle documentation. Implementation specifics of Oracle do not necessarily apply to MySQL. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I actually meant to reference MySQL's driver implementations. How does MySQL driver implement the buffering/streaming process of database data?

Comment: @TylerMutai Edt rejected. You didn't read it in the Javadoc, you read it in the [Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide, 11g Release 2 (11.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm). This is part of the Oracle Database product, not of Java. If you want to know how the MySQL driver implements it, look at the MySQL documentation.